# Running a contains function in Amazon Quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am trying to a comparison for values in a column in a table using Contain or IN function in QuickSight, but I cannot get it to work.

For example

this should return a False/Non-redundant because both Account-1 and Account-2 are using the same ISP

| ISPs | Accounts |
| --- | --- |
| ISP-1 | Account-1 |
| ISP-1 | Account-2 |

However, this should return a Positive/Redundant because both Account-1 and Account-2 are using different ISPs

| ISPs | Accounts |
| --- | --- |
| ISP-1 | Account-1 |
| ISP-2 | Account-2 |